# Joining Several tables at once:

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-error-1066

I'm using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT reply.id, reply.content, author.username
FROM thread, reply, author
JOIN thread_reply ON thread.id = thread_reply.thread_id
JOIN reply ON thread_reply.reply_id = reply.id
JOIN author_reply ON thread.id = author_reply.thread_id
JOIN author ON author_reply.author_id = author.id
WHERE thread.id = '40'
```

I have the follwing tables:

```
thread_reply: thread_id, reply_id

reply: id, content, created (timestamp)

author: id, username, password_hash, salt #etc

thread: id, content, created

author_reply: author_id, reply_id
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'reply'
```

Oh and I'm using MySQL.

Comment: You shouldn't explicitly select from `reply` and `author` if you're going to join them.

Comment: What is the point of `thread_reply` and `author_reply` tables? Can one reply refer to multiple threads? Can one reply have multiple authors?

Comment: I deleted that after I realised that it had nothing to do with this... as I said, my head hurts, insomnia

Comment: This is yet another reason why implicit joins should never be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT reply.id, reply.content, author.username
FROM thread
INNER JOIN thread_reply ON thread.id = thread_reply.thread_id
INNER JOIN reply ON thread_reply.reply_id = reply.id
INNER JOIN author_reply ON thread.id = author_reply.thread_id
INNER JOIN author ON author_reply.author_id = author.id
WHERE thread.id = '40'
```

Comment: you're right, it should be INNER JOIN author_reply ON reply.id = author_reply.reply_id

Comment: I've selected this because It helped be come to the right answer

Answer (score 3):

You had an implicit `CROSS JOIN` between `thread`, `author` and `reply` in your original query, and joined the same tables for the second time without aliasing them.

Use this:

```
SELECT  reply.id, reply.content, author.username
FROM    thread t
JOIN    thread_reply tr
ON      tr.thread_id = t.id
JOIN    reply r
ON      r.id = tr.reply_id
JOIN    author_reply ar
ON      ar.reply_id = r.id
JOIN    author a
ON      a.id = ar.author_id
WHERE   thread.id = '40'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are including tables in the `FROM` clause and then joining to them as well - I think you want simply `FROM thread`, and then your joins.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error on the row that says

```
JOIN author_reply ON thread.id = author_reply.thread_id
```

there is no thread_id in your author_reply table according to the definitions given.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT reply.id, reply.content, author.username
FROM thread
JOIN thread_reply ON thread.id = thread_reply.thread_id
JOIN reply ON thread_reply.reply_id = reply.id
JOIN author_reply ON reply.id = author_reply.reply_id
JOIN author ON author_reply.author_id = author.id
WHERE thread.id = '40'
```